# Solr Spell Check

Tags: solr, spell-checking

I am working with Solr Spell Check . Got it up and running . However for certain misspells it is not giving the expected result :

Correct Word : Cancer

Incorrect Spelling : Cacner ,cacnar , cancar ,cancre,cancere .

I am not getting "cancer" as the suggestion for "cacnar" instead it shows "inner" which although sounds more like cacner is not the correct suggestion . And for cacnar again I am getting a suggestion as 'pulmonary'.

Any way of configuring it to display cancer instead of the other results ?

Alternatively is there any score for the suggestions that can be referred to before showing it to the user ?

As per request here is the configuration :
The field used for dictionary (in schema.xml):

```
<copyField source="procname"  dest="dtextspell" />
 <field name = "dtextspell" stored="false" type="text_small" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Definition of "text_small" (again in schema.xml) :

```
<fieldType name="text_small" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
              <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
     <analyzer type ="query">
              <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>    

     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In solrconfig.xml :

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_small</str>
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
   <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
    <str name="field">dtextspell</str>
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.0001</float>

  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
   <str name="field">name</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

</lst></searchComponent>
```

Attached it to the select request handler like this :

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">

 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
   <str name="df">text</str>
 </lst>
 <arr name="last-components">
   <str>spellcheck</str>
 </arr>   </requestHandler>
```

To build the spell check :

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*:*&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

To search for term :

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=procname:%22cacner%22&spellcheck=true&defType=edismax
```

The response XML :

```
<lst name="spellcheck"><lst name="suggestions">
     <lst name="cacner">
     <int name="numFound">1</int>
     <int name="startOffset">10</int>
     <int name="endOffset">16</int>
      <arr name="suggestion">
     <str>inner</str> <end tags start from here>
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: did you configure the spellchecker or you're using the default one? can i see, if you have any, some of your code or at least the url you're using to query solr? :)

Comment: Hey , added the code as you requested .

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo  I'm also have similar problem but little bit different in my case Spell corrections & Suggestions working fine.... Please take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196793/how-get-suggestions-from-solr-server-in-a-php-variable

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've not rebuilt the spellchecker's index recently. Request a manual update by make a query with `spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true` appended to the query string (do NOT do this on every request, as the build process can take some time). You should also make sure that you're using the correct field to build your spellchecker's index.

You can also configure the spellchecker component to [rebuild the index on every commit](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Building_on_Commits) or [on every optimize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Building_on_Optimize), by adding:

```
<str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
```

or

```
<str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
```

to your spellchecker configuration.

Comment: Hey , I am currently working on it , so the spell check has been built quite repeatedly . The field is correct as well , because I am getting the correct spellings for other sample terms . I will be editing my answer to include my comment soon , you can have a look and tell me if something is wrong .

Comment: I'm also have similar problem but little bit different in my case Spell corrections & Suggestions working fine.... Please take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196793/how-get-suggestions-from-solr-server-in-a-php-variable